# How to assign properties to a SwiftUI Button in a grid

Tags: swiftui

this seems like it should not be so hard, and yet...

so I have a grid of buttons, say, 3x3 for simplicity. In each square, there's a button:

```
Grid(horizontalSpacing: 0, verticalSpacing: 0) {
    ForEach(0..<boardSize, id: \.self) { row in
        GridRow {
            ForEach(0..<boardSize, id: \.self) { col in
                GeometryReader { gridCellSize in
                    Rectangle()
                        .foregroundColor(.teal)
                        .overlay(Text("\(row),\(col)").fontWeight(.heavy))
                        .border(Color.black)
                    Button {
                        
                    } label: {
                        Text("")
                            .frame(width: gridCellSize.frame(in: .global).width ,
                                   height: gridCellSize.frame(in: .global).height)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

what I want to do is assign a set of properties to the button, such as a UUID, a name, and a set of coordinates that correspond to its grid location. Here's a struct I built, but it can be a class too, i'm not tied to either:

```
struct buttonData {
    var buttonID = UUID()
    var buttonContents: String
    var buttonCoords: (buttonX: Int, buttonY: Int)
}
```

so now I have the data I care about (and I'm not tied to this method either, if someone has a better way, cool).

What I am utterly failing it is assigning those properties to the button in a way that lets me reference it on a click. I can use a state var or a stateobject var, but I get one version of that, and I need anywhere between 9 and 100 depending on grid size (the user can change the grid size from 3x3 to 10x10)

At some point, I need to be able to reference the buttons from an outside function, hence the buttonID and buttonCoords, but I can't even ASSIGN the values much less use them.

(tl;dr of backstory - it's for a project building an SOS game where you try to build "SOS" on a game board)

what I have so far in "completed" form is at: https://github.com/johncwelch/SOS-Swift

I've tried using state vars, no love, I only get one copy of those. I've tried assigning the vars in onAppear(), but I can't reference them in action{} because they're not created yet. StateObjects give me the same results as state vars. About all I haven't tried is globals.

I fully admit I could be missing something here. Clearly I am or i'd not need help.

Comment: You already have access to `row` and `col` inside the buttons action closure. Is that not sufficient?

Comment: Can you show your attempts? Otherwise I'm not sure where exactly you are having trouble with, and what you want to do.

Comment: What do you mean when you say you will need to access butin from outside ? You do not access UI element in SwiftUI (only with UIKit you can do this). In SwiftUI you have State vars that contains what your app is about. All other stuff is how you draw thing and how you use orrepresent your state var . You can have an array of ButtonData, and you access either by ForEach on array or by using row and col from your loop.

Comment: All you need is the action you intend the `Button` to trigger. Say you have a func that asks the user what letter they want to place at the tapped location, either "S" or "O". That function could be `func sOrO(col: Int, row: Int)`.  In the `Button` you would simply call `sOrO(col: col, row: row)`. The func would have all the data it needed to work. The OS will keep track of the values of `col` and `row` for that button for you. What you need to track is not the buttons, but the states of the squares, most likely in a 2D array. That is what you need to model.

Comment: first, thanks to everyone commenting, your time is appreciated. In terms of what happens on a click (My current attempt is in the github i linked to): 

Basically, when someone clicks a button, its label can have three states: blank, S, and O.

When the state is either S or O, i need all the buttons with blank labels to be inaccessible so that a player can only change the state of one button.

cont'd

Comment: When the button is set to the right state, the player will click a "save move" button or similar, and then a few things happen:

If the current button label is "S" then check to see if any adjacent buttons are "O". If yes, then is the next button in a straight line an "S". If so, the player has completed SOS, the color of the buttons in that line are set to blue or red, and that player's score is incremented.

if the current button is "O" then the buttons around that new "O" are checked. If there's an "S" on both sides in a straight line, then SOS, button color changes to reflect player...

Comment: and the score is incremented for that player, and it's the other player's turn

If there is no "SOS" completed, no score changes, and it's the other player's turn.

Conceptually, this is not hard, I can see it in my head how to run the buttons. Even inefficiently, it's not a lot going on, so it'll be fast. But I need to be able to track button states independently, and then change properties of existing buttons that aren't the one just clicked, and that's the part i'm having a devil of a time with.

Comment: yrb, the 2D array part I understand, what I'm not getting is how to say, when I click on the square at 1,0 to read the state of the square at 1,1  and then 1,2 to see if I've spelled SOS or not. 

that's the part that I am completly unable to figure out.